# Firebase multiple iOS app sms signup

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my firebase project, I have 2 apps. One for the user and one for the driver. I'm using phone/sms authentication + email and password for user to signup.

It's working fine if the user is using a different phone/phone number to signup to two different apps.

However, when I signup using the same phone/phone number to both apps(in the case where I can be a user and also a driver), it throws this error to me:

> Signup error: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17015
>   "[ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] - User can only be linked to one
>   identity for the given provider."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=[ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] -
>   User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider.,
>   error_name=ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED}

Answer (score 0):

That's because Phone Authentication only allows a single session per user. You can not be logged in on 2 devices at the same time, for security reasons.

If you want to allow your users to login to both apps at the same time, you should consider using a different Auth Provider. Maybe Email/Password.

Comment: I'm using 1 device with 2 apps and 1 phone number. So means it's not possible for a phone to be a user and driver?

Comment: In a single app that only a single user can be signed in at any one time. But if these are separate apps, that should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED` is thrown when you can try to link a credential to a Firebase user when that user already has a credential linked for that type of provider.

In your situation, I speculate, the user already has a phone number and you are trying to link another phone credential to the same user.

Comment: Yes... the user first sign up for the "user app" using phone number (#1) and email+password(#1). Then he decided that he wants to be a driver as well by downloading the "driver app" using phone number (#1) and email+password (#1). Both apps resides on the same phone. How to cater for this scenario? So before linking the email+password to the phone, we need to check if the current phone number is already link to a email and password?